# Working with second python version in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, versions

I need to work with python version 3.5 in order to run and modify a script containing pyqt5. I am currenly running python 3.6.

I would like to know how I download python 3.5 and install pyqt5 for that environment and then make it available for pycharm community edition. I have tried to use anaconda to manage a second python version but it is not working. Keeps giving me pyqt5 not found. Thank you

Comment: Suggestion: Use `pyenv`. However, what exactly isn't working between these two python versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new virtual environment with `conda` using the following command and specify the required version. More info on [conda create](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html#installing-a-different-version-of-python)

`conda create -n py35 python=3.5`

it will install the Python3.5 on your system most likely in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs`  You can then add that python version in Pycharm as the project interpreter using

`File -> Settings --> Project --> Project Interpreter`

Click on the Setttings icon in the right pane & locate the Python version on your system and then add it as the python version for this project.

Refer Pycharm [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks when I ran the .py file from pycharm in this manner it still have me module not found error for import pyqt5. How can I install pyqt5 to be available in pycharm under package? Currently just shows pip and setuptools under package in python for py35 interpreter

Comment: Once you have set the project interpreter, you can install packages using the `+` symbol in Pycharm.  Or install directly from your `conda` environment after activating it using `pip`

Comment: Or you can install `pyqt5` while creating the environment with `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 pyqt5`

Answer (score 1):

I would use `virtualenv` and configre `pycharm` to use it. It is more demanding but fully independent.

look [here](http://pymote.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install/windows_virtualenv.html) on how to setup virtualenv and the packages that you need

Than do this in `pycharm` so it can use the `enviorment` that you create.

```
Select File, click Settings.
In the left pane, enter Project Interpreter in the search box, then click Project Interpreter.
In the right pane, click the gear icon, click More….
In the Project Interpreters dialog box, click the plus sign +, click Add Local.
Enter ~/virtualenvs/<your virtualenv name>/bin/python in the path. If you followed the earlier post to setup a virtual environment for Python then enter ~/virtualenvs/api/bin/python.
Click OK.
Select 2.7.6 virtualenv at ~/virtualenvs/api, click the edit icon.
Check Associate this virtual environment with current project.
Click OK.
Click OK.
Click Apply, click OK
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a different version of Python in Pycharm, install the specific version for python and install it normally. You can find the version from the Python website. After installing, open Pycharm project, then go to File>Settings>Project: Project Interpreter. Under the project interpreter select the python version that you want to associate with the project. Click apply and that's it.

See the attached image for guidance.[image]